# $[(f')^2 + f^2]' = 2(f'f'' + ff')$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My textbook states the following:

> We have $f'' + f = 0$.
>
> Multiplying both sides of this equation by $f'$ yields $f''f' + f'f = 0$.
>
> Thus $[(f')^2 + f^2]' = 2(f'f'' + ff') = 0 $.

I don't understand (1) how the book got the expression $[(f')^2 + f^2]'$ and (2) how $[(f')^2 + f^2]' = 2(f'f'' + ff')$.

I understand differentiation, but I do not understand how they've done the above calculations; perhaps due to the abstract notation.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this. Also, please show your calculations and reasoning step-by-step so that I may learn.

Comment: they've used the chain rule, taking  $f^2 = g(f(x))$ where $g(x) = x^2$ would you be able to differentiate that?  Also they used the additive rule of differentiation to add the two terms together.

Comment: what if you said $f = \sin x$ would you be able to do that as an example?

Comment: I did an example without the abstractness and applied the chain rule. But what about what Tsemo said in his answer? Is it the chain rule or the power rule?

Comment: to my mind, the power rule is a subset of the chain-rule - $g(f(x))$ where $g(x) = x^n$ then $(f(x)^n)' = nf'(x)(f(x))^{(n-1)}$ derived by chain rule

Comment: @Cato Thank your for the assistance. I understand now.

Comment: A hint about simple particular cases

$ f= \sin x, \, f' = \cos x ;\, f^{''} = -f, \, $

$ f^2+ f^{'2  } = 1,\, $

$ 2\,1' =0 \,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f = f(x)$ then by using the product rule, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f^{2} &= \frac{d}{dx} (f f) \\\\
&= \frac{df}{dx} \cdot f + f \cdot \frac{df}{dx} \\\\
&= f' f + f f' \\\\
&= 2f f'
\end{align}

Similarly for the $f'^{2}$ case

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f'^{2} &= \frac{d}{dx} (f' f') \\\\
&= \frac{df'}{dx} \cdot f' + f' \cdot \frac{df'}{dx} \\\\
&= f'' f' + f' f'' \\\\
&= 2f' f''
\end{align}

Putting these together

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f^{2} + \frac{d}{dx} f'^{2} &= \frac{d}{dx} [f^{2} + f'^{2}] \\\\
&= 2[ff' + f'f'']
\end{align}

Note that the multiplication through the original equation by $f'$ is a well known technique used to solve ODEs, for example, when solving the KDV equation after making a travelling wave ansatz.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply the formula $(f^n)'=nf^{n-1}f'$ to $(({f'}^2+f^2)'=({f'}^2)'+(f^2)'=2f'f"+2ff'.$

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the power rule, shouldn't it be $(f^n)' = nf^{n-1}$ only?

Comment: The power rule is $(f^n)'=nf^{n-1}f'$.

Comment: But since $(f^n)'$ is actually $g(f(x))$ where $g(x) = x^n$, shouldn't we be using the chain rule?

Comment: Both could be used, and should give the same answer - the beauty of this is you could also use the product rule $f^2 = f.f$ differentiate with product rule to get $f.f' + f'.f = 2 f.f'$ that would also extend to powers of n